# Return range input parameters from function in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, input, range

I am using a range input, however require the `step`,`min`,`max` and `value` to be set dynamically within an `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="paramObj in activeExercise.Params track by $index">
    <div class="item item-divider">
        {{paramObj.param}}: {{paramObj.childParam || 0}}
    </div>
    <div ng-if="checkRangeItems(paramObj)" class="item range">
        <i class="icon orange" ng-class="paramClass(paramObj.param)"></i>
        <input type="range" name="parameter" ng-model="paramObj.childParam" min="0" step="{{paramObj.paramStep}}" max="" value="0">
    </div>
</div>
```

An example of my data object is:

```
[{"param":"Sets"},{"param":"Reps"},{"param":"Weight"},{"param":"Color"},{"param":"Time (Sec)"},{"param":"Time (Min)"},{"param":"Hold"},{"param":"Tempo"}]
```

I need to set the range values dependent on the value of `param.param`.

Something ***like*** this:

```
$scope.getVars = function(paramObj) {

    switch (paramObj.param) {
        case "Sets":
            return {max: 90, min: 0, step: 10};
            break;

        case "Reps":
            return {max: 90, min: 0, step: 10};
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Can you display some more code for getting exact understanding

Answer (score 1):

Yes, It's possible!

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('indexCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.title = 'HTML5 - Range';
  $scope.min = 0;
  $scope.max = 50;
  $scope.step = 10;
  $scope.value = 20;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="indexCtrl">
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    Min: <input type="text" ng-model="min"><br/>
    Max: <input type="text" ng-model="max"><br/>
    Step: <input type="text" ng-model="step"><br/>
     Value:<input type="text" ng-model="value"><br/>
    <input type="range" ng-model="value" name="points" min="{{min}}" max="{{max}}" step="{{step}}" />
    
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I neglected to mention that this is within a ng-repeat so things are a little more complex than setting the values to $scope

Comment: It's not a complex one; just replace the $scope variables into your object values. Simple!

Comment: You did two mistakes in your code: 1. you didn't specify the curly braces when assigning a value to 'min', 'max' and 'step' attributes 2. You don't need to specify the 'value' attribute inside the input element when you are using 'ng-model' directive